# Why can't GHC deduce this type?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following code snippet (from http://lpaste.net/180651):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

class Natural n

newtype V n a = V [a]

dim :: Natural n => V n a -> Int
dim = undefined -- defined in my actual code

bad_fromList :: Natural n => [a] -> V n a
bad_fromList l = if length l == dim v then v else undefined -- this is line 11
  where v = V l

good_fromList :: forall n a. Natural n => [a] -> V n a
good_fromList l = if length l == dim v then v else undefined
  where v = V l :: V n a
```

GHCI gives the following error message:

```
test.hs:11:33: error:
    • Could not deduce (Natural n0) arising from a use of ‘dim’
      from the context: Natural n
        bound by the type signature for:
                   bad_fromList :: Natural n => [a] -> V n a
        at test.hs:10:1-41
      The type variable ‘n0’ is ambiguous
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘dim v’
      In the expression: length l == dim v
      In the expression: if length l == dim v then v else undefined
```

Why can't GHCI deduce the type?

Or, in the following code, pure' and good_f compile, while bad_f gives a similar error message. Why?

```
pure' :: Natural n => a -> V n a
pure' x = v
  where v = V $ replicate (dim v) x

bad_f :: Natural n => [a] -> (V n a, Int)
bad_f xs = (v, dim v)
  where v = V xs

good_f :: Natural n => a -> (V n a, Int)
good_f x = (v, dim v)
  where v = V $ replicate (dim v) x
```

Comment: The problem is that `v` has type `V n a` for **all** possible types `n`. Given that Haskell relies on the open world assumption there is no way to know which instance of `Natural n` should be used there and thus the error where it says that `n0` is ambiguous: GHC doesn't want to choose a random type to be able to call `dim`. You must make your code not ambiguous.

Comment: The types here aren't actually ambiguous, these errors are due to the fact that the compiler tries to infer more general type signatures than required. Your code [works](https://ideone.com/GsEHSO) if you enable `-XMonoLocalBinds`.

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks! Are there any downsides to using MonoLocalBinds?

Comment: @Kevin When you use `MonoLocalBinds`, the compiler no longer does `let` generaliztion (this is the definition of what the extension does). For a very detailed explanation of exactly how the typechecker handles `let` bindings with and w/o `MonoLocalBinds`, see [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/blog/LetGeneralisationInGhc7). In short, if you declare a function which you would like to be polymorphic in a `let` block, then to give it that polymorphic type, you will *always* have to give it a type signature, even if the polymorphic type is inferrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user2407038 suggested, enabling -XMonoLocalBinds makes the code work.